# How to prevent sedimentation of an EDTA suspension?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, colloids

I tried to create a suspension of **EDTA powder in glycerin with 1:1 ratio**. *I keep facing problem of EDTA sedimentation*. I've tried other ratios also but this was the only one which formed least amount of sediment.

When I used coarse powder, the sediment formed within 24 hours but when finely ground powder was used, the same occurred but after 3 days. I even tried heating the powder & glycerin together on low & medium heat but EDTA sediment still forms but with varied time.

I'd like that the suspension remain consistent irrespective of how much time goes by.
I read on the internet that anti-settling agents (like xanthan gum & microfibrillated cellulose) can be used but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Is shaking/mixing before usage a problem ? There is probably no way but increasing the viscosity, what may affect the medical usage. Sedimentation may be affected by surfactants, but so does the medical usage as well. Mixing is the safest way.

Comment: Shaking & mixing is quite difficult once the powder settles due to viscosity of the glycerin especially once the mixture is placed in the test tube.

Comment: Be aware clarification because of incomplete or missing information means extra effort on both sides. Provide all possibly relevant background when asking.

Comment: Please, clarify. I've already mentioned all the details in the question...

Comment: You have not mentioned there why mixing is not easily applicable. Is applicable reversing orientation during storage ? Any additives may affect the medical application, but you provided no medical context. Somebody may advice the way how to stabilize the suspension, which would work, but would be totally not applicable for the purpose of the suspension. And there is still hanging danger of misguiding with medical consequences, at the edge of being off-topic for this site.

Comment: If you must know, I'm researching for a biochemistry paper. As the paper is confidential, I can't divulge much information about it due to institutional policy. However, the part for which I couldn't find any reasonable solution was the EDTA sedimentation therefore I put forth my query here to find an answer. If people here are unable to help, I'll ask elsewhere.

Comment: We're still in the experimental stage so whatever is told will be thoroughly tested before it's even considered for trials. Don't worry about it. This conversation hasn't been very fruitful. There are plenty of other chemistry forums out there. I'll ask my question there. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Easy there, fella. Not knowing something is one thing but personal attacks... That's low. And I mean really low...

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. And btw I never made any personal comments.

Comment: Well, "conversation with you was not very fruitful" and "You were not helpful either. " are at the same level. :-) I.e. None meant personally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118464/discussion-between-poutnik-and-sohail-sa).

Answer (score 3):

I see 4 possibilties to avoid EDTA sedimentation:

1. **Mechanical** ways like shaking, mixing or container turning - but you say it is not applicable.
2. Increasing **viscosity** by thickening glycerol to  decrease the rate of sedimentation. Gel stages could probably even stop the sedimentation, but may not be applicable. You may want to try

   - [Carboxymethyl cellulose (CMC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboxymethyl_cellulose)
   - [Polyvinyl alcohol(PVA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinyl_alcohol)
   - [Polyvinylpyrrolidone/polyvidone/povidone (PVP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinylpyrrolidone)
   - [Polyethylene glycol(PEG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_glycol)
3. Other way would have been adjusting the glycerol **density** to match EDTA density if [EDTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylenediaminetetraacetic_acid) had not had too low density $\pu{0.86 g/cm^3}$ ( while [glycerol](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycerol)  $\pu{1.26 g/cm^3}$). OTOH, if there was a chance to replace glycerol by ethanol 73 w/w %, having the [same density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol_(data_page)#Density_of_ethanol_at_various_temperatures) as EDTA has ... but I guess  there is not.
4. It may be worthy to try some [**emulsifiers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsion#Emulsifiers), but EDTA particles may be too large and emulsifiers may not be applicable for the suspension purpose.

> - [Soy lecithin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecithin) is another emulsifier and thickener
> - [Pickering stabilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickering_emulsion) – uses particles under certain circumstances
> - Sodium phosphates - not directly an emulsifier, but modifies behavior of other molecules, e.g. caesin
> - [Mono- and diglycerides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono-_and_diglycerides_of_fatty_acids) - a common emulsifier found in many food products (coffee creamers, ice-creams, spreads, breads, cakes)
> - [Sodium stearoyl lactylate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_stearoyl_lactylate)
> - [DATEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DATEM) (diacetyl tartaric acid esters of mono- and diglycerides) – an emulsifier used primarily in baking
> - Simple cellulose – a [particulate emulsifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickering_emulsion) derived from plant material using only water

Comment: Mechanical mixing wasn't an option as after sedimentation EDTA in Glycerol becomes quite hard to mix.

Comment: Lowering density was an option but I'm unsure of how that can be achieved? Would appreciate more clarification...

Comment: I haven't tried cellulose yet. Will do that & get back to you. But (just a thought) don't you think cellulose won't work as it's water soluble. Will it mix into Glycerol?

Comment: @SohailSA aboue density:  You may have noticed the 3rd conditional - a conditional not achivable in past, present or future. The only option would be replacing glycerol by less dense solvent, what is not probably applicable. Celullose is not soluble. You have not commented reversing orientation.

Comment: Will using xanthan gum be of any help?

Comment: No experience with that.

Comment: Can't replace Glycerol as the experiment requires a material that can also act as a lubricant. Can you suggest any other solvent that could serve as a good alternative?

Comment: You know, advising to a black box is like an ordering a meal in a restaurant where waiters would not say what they have, but only what they do not have if you ask for it. Ordering by trials and errors would get old pretty fast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118492/discussion-between-poutnik-and-sohail-sa).

Comment: My apologies. I was using this forum for the first time therefore didn't understand when you asked me to continue through chat.

Comment: It is rather forced by the site policy and administrators/moderators, as comments below Qs/As are not intended for discussion. Note the StackExchange sites generally, and so does Chemistry SE are NOT (discussion) forums, but Questions/Answers sites, aiming to high quality of both. So there is big difference between ordinary forums like Quora or topical forums on 1 side and SE on other side.